# Memory efficient way to print summary of dataset

Tags: r, performance, memory-management, bigdata

I have a dataset with the following structure:

```
require(data.table)
train <- data.table(sample(1:10, 10), runif(10, 0, 10))
```

However, the dataset is ~ 7,5 GB in memory and has ~630 million rows. Attempting `summary(train)` yields in an error: `Error: cannot allocate vector of size 2.3 Gb`. I can extract some information by manually calling `train[, mean(V2)]`, `train[, min(V2)]` and `train[, max(V2)]`, but median and quantiles will result in OOM. Is there a possibility to make these operations on a 16GB RAM machine? 
An idea would be to split the dataset but that would be a bit cumbersome w.r.t to median and quantiles

Comment: `sapply(train, summary)` ?

Comment: Or work on one vector at a time. You might also look into storing the numeric variables as a matrix and then use the `bigmemory` package to calculate such statistics.

Comment: @YalDan feedback?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, took a 2-days digital detox and didn't see the amazing effort you put into this

`sapply(train, summary)` gave me the exact same OOM message, but the idea was where I was aiming to as well. @Imo I believe that's what the solution by @minem with `sapply` would do anyway right? 

Regarding the `bigmemory` package: It's painfully slow to load the data, but I was able to get the `median`, `min` and `max` value. Unfortunately, quantiles result in OOM. Also, while slower than `ff`, I preferred it because it was easier to use. I will now check your answer @minem, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I came up with function `summaryI`, to which we supply our interested column name:

```
summaryI <- function(i2) {
  setorderv(train, i2)
  N <- train[, .N]

  # count NAs:
  # nas <- is.na(train[[i2]])
  # nNA <- sum(nas)
  # OR
  i <- 1L
  nNA <- 0L
  while (is.na(train[[i2]][i])) {
    nNA <- nNA + 1L
    i <- i + 1L
  }
  nNA
  # will be slow if many NAs, but more memory efficient
  # (will not create additional vector)

  n <- N - nNA
  probs <- seq(0, 1, 0.25)
  # quantiles, only type = 7
  index <- 1 + (n - 1) * probs
  lo <- floor(index)
  hi <- ceiling(index)
  qs <- train[[i2]][lo + nNA]
  i <- which(index > lo)
  h <- (index - lo)[i]
  qs[i] <- (1 - h) * qs[i] + h * train[[i2]][hi[i] + nNA]
  qs # quantile results

  rmean <- sum(train[[i2]], na.rm = T) / n

  qq <- c(qs[1L:3L], rmean, qs[4L:5L])
  digits <- max(3L, getOption("digits") - 3L)
  qq <- signif(qq, digits)
  names(qq) <- c("Min.", "1st Qu.", "Median", "Mean", "3rd Qu.", "Max.")
  if (nNA > 0L) { # to match summary output
    c(qq, `NA's` = nNA)
    } else {
      qq
    }
}
```

The basic idea is that we order the interested column in place (with `setorder` from `data.table`) and then try to do all the calculations without copying data.

As mentioned in comments, if your data have a lot of NAs then this will be slow.
But hopefully you will be able to run on all of the data. Also, I hard coded inside NA management.

Example:

```
summaryI('V2')
# Min.   1st Qu.    Median      Mean   3rd Qu.      Max.      NA's 
# 2.398e-08 2.501e-01 5.000e-01 5.000e-01 7.500e-01 1.000e+00 1.000e+02
```

or run over multiple columns, like:

```
sapply(colnames(train), summaryI)
```

The source code of `summary` and `quantile`, which I used as basis, can be found:

[github quantile.R](https://github.com/SurajGupta/r-source/blob/master/src/library/stats/R/quantile.R)

[github summary.R](https://github.com/SurajGupta/r-source/blob/a28e609e72ed7c47f6ddfbb86c85279a0750f0b7/src/library/base/R/summary.R)

Comment: What can I say... This is brilliant, gives me the summary for the columns in less than five minutes, which is significantly faster than working with bigmemory packages. Checking for validity of results:
~~~
`> train <- data.table(1:100, 1:100)`
`> summary(train$V1)`
`Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. `
`1.00   25.75   50.50   50.50   75.25  100.00` 
`> summaryI('V1')`
`Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. `
`1.00   25.75   50.50   50.50   75.25  100.00 `
~~~

Apparently they do the same!

Wish I could give you more than one upvote, really appreciate your effort!

Comment: Sorry, the code formatting looks awful, anyway just wanted to highlight that the results are indeed truthful!